# Using php facebook sdk in joomla

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, joomla

Here is the sample what i have used for a social login in joomla.
Iam having a problem to get extended permission so that i can recieve there email id..

```
 $facebookuser  =   @$_SESSION['facebookuser'];

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                'appId' => $params->get('fb_appid'),
                'secret' => $params->get('fb_appsecret'),
                'cookie' => true
            ));

    $session =& JFactory::getSession();
    $session->set( 'facebook', $facebook );

    if(empty($facebookuser))
    {
        $session = $facebook->getUser();

        if (!empty($session)) 
        {
            # Active session, let's try getting the user id (getUser()) and user info (api->('/me'))
            try {
                $uid = $facebook->getUser();

                $user   = $facebook->api('/me');

            } catch (Exception $e) {
            }

            if (!empty($user)) 
            {
                $fbobject   = new facebookloginHelper();
                $storefb    = $fbobject->fbstoreuser($user);

            } else 
            {
                # For testing purposes, if there was an error, let's kill the script
                die("There was an error.");
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            # There's no active session, let's generate one
            //$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
            $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                   'canvas' => 1,
                   'fbconnect' => 0,
                   'req_perms' => 'publish_stream,email',
                   'next' => 'http://www.oyeparty.com/bangalore',
                   'cancel_url' => 'http://www.oyeparty.com/bangalore'
              ));
           //header("Location: " . $login_url);
        }
    }
```

Please help me.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use JFacebook?

Comment: I have no idea regarding JFacebook..

Comment: So you should look at that package and see if you can use it to do what you want,  a lot of the code is already written.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=202020556638870&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.some.com%2F&state=c3900422cab698db3d680804e77abf32&req_perms=publish_stream%2Cemail&next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.some.com%2Fbangalore&cancel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.some.com%2F This is the href attribute but still it is not asking for extended permission...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if Joomla has a custom Facebook PHP SDK but the code presented above doesn't match the latest Official Facebook PHP SDK

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

With this being the way to get `email` permissions

```
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'publish_stream,email',
  'redirect_uri' => 'http://www.oyeparty.com/bangalore'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=202020556638870&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.some.com%2F&state=c3900422cab698db3d680804e77abf32&req_perms=publish_stream%2Cemail&next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.some.com%2Fbangalore&cancel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.some.com%2F This is the href attribute but still it is not asking for extended permission...